# How to convert a gray image of a letter to binary without losing the main contour?

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

I have a small gray-scale image with a number on it. In order to try my OCR method on it I have to convert it into binary.

If I use cvThreshold with 127 as threshold the image looks all screwed up because of the gradient around the skeletons of the number. I tried but could not find any image sharpening functions to use before applying the threshold.

Does anyone have pointers please?

[image: original gray scale image] becomes [image] which is crude.

EDIT: by binary, I mean binary image, where a pixel in the image is either 0 (black) or 255 (white).

EDIT2: Oh, looking at the revision log made me giggle.

Comment: I hope that was a Freudian slip.

Comment: I am new to image processing, so if I miss worded anything, or committed a silly blunder in something obvious, please don't be afraid to hurt my feelings.

Comment: @Haoest: It seems some friendly individual already edited the title to remove the "gay image". Have you tried a different threshold?

Comment: I find 255*0.75 pretty satisfying, however, that threshold would only work well for 1 particular input image. I need to find a more general solution. I tried my own version of histogram too, but didn't yield too much success.

Comment: @Haoest That doesn't seem right. Many of the gradients in that image scape from the 127 threshold and should not end up in the result. Where is your code? Check my updated answer for directions.

Comment: @karlphilip you are right that's not the threshold that produces the fat 6, but so far I haven't found a static threshold that works for all numbers yet, that's why I wanted a function to find the most optimal for each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play with the threshold variable first. You may find a result that satisfies you without having to add any more processing to your application. What about using 120, 110 or 100?

Anyway, **I didn't got the same output as you** using 127 as parameter. Maybe your are doing something different on your side. Check my code:

```
IplImage* input_img = cvLoadImage("6.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
if(!input_img)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Failed to load input image" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

cvThreshold(input_img, input_img, 127, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

if( !cvSaveImage("out.png", input_img) )
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: Failed to write image file" << std::endl;
}    

cvReleaseImage(&input_img);
```

**Input**: [image] **Output**: [image]

Comment: I see what you mean. You are right about the 6; 127 threshold does yield your result. I've been tweaking the threshold all day and got confused a bit. There just isn't a universal threshold that works for all numbers at the same time. For example, 127 produces a pretty bad "4" (http://i.imgur.com/mNyqI.png). What do you think if I just keep the high threshold that produces the fat 6, and update my OCR template for 6 to look like it?

Comment: You should do that since it won't add any more weight on the CPU. You can't exaggerate on the processing and risk loosing performance, right? But there might some light processing that could help you in this case. What if you pre-process your images with `cvSmooth(CV_BLUR)` right before executing the threshold operation? This can be a way to answer your universal threshold question. Note that this requires you to search for a new threshold parameter too. If you have a couple of hours to test, it's worth trying it.

Comment: I don't think it'll make a difference in performance because it compares the whole grid anyways. Thanks for your input. That's what I am going to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are some handy image processing algorithms for doing this over at [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com).

See [BradleyLocalThresholding](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/0ad5b988-5613-d62a-22a9-cf41e39c139f.htm) for adaptive thresholding.

Comment: I will use some crude method to work around this issue at the moment -- naming update the template to match the fat characters. If that turns out to be insufficient, I will port the C# code over. Thanks.